# Creating links in query from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have searched many sites but I can't find how to create links from a query I made with mysql.

I want that when somebody clicks on the coureurname he/she is redirected to another page, but how do i make click able links from these query results. I posted my query with php code here below, I hope you guys can help me because I really don't know how to do this.

```
<html>
<title> lijstcoureur</title>
<head>
<H1> LIJST VAN COUREURS </H1>
</head>

<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','****')
or die ('Kan geen verbinding maken met mySQL server');

$db=mysql_select_db('formule1',$con)
or die ('Kan de database niet selecteren');

$selectie=mysql_query("CALL lijstcoureurs()",$con);
if(!selectie)
die('Invalid query:'.mysql_error());
?>
<table border =1>

                        <thead>

                                <tr>
<?php

                                        for($fieldindex=0;$fieldindex<mysql_num_fields($selectie);$fieldindex++)

                                        {

                                                echo '<th>';

                                                echo mysql_field_name($selectie,$fieldindex);

                                                echo '</th>';

                                        }

                                        ?>

                                </tr>

                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                                <?php

                                /*

                                Loop alle rijen langs en sla het resultaat op in variable $row */

                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selectie))
                                        {


                                                // Begin een nieuwe rij
                                                echo('<tr>');

                                                // Loop alle rijen langs en zet de inhoud in de tabel
                                                for($fieldindex=0;$fieldindex<mysql_num_fields($selectie);$fieldindex++)

                                                {

                                                        echo('<td>');

                                                        echo($row[$fieldindex]);

                                                        echo('</td>');


                                                }

                                                echo('</tr>');

                                        }

                                ?>

                        </tbody>

                </table>

        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `echo($row[$fieldindex]);` contains the link, you can do it like this:

```
echo "<a href=" . $row[$fieldindex] . ">Anchor text here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the query result from the database into the `href` attribute of a `<a>` tag.

For example:

```
<a href="<?php echo $queryResult; ?>"> My Query Result </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. Does your table contain URLs, which you want to display as links? Then just wrap them in `<a>`-tags. If, on the other hand, you want to display a special page (like a detail view) upon clicking on a row - you'll have to implement functionality for that.

Example:

```
// Assuming $row contains the record's database ID at index 0
echo '<a href="/some_url/on/your/server?id=' . $row[0] . "'>Anchor text here</a>';
```

This will make a link to a special URL and pass the id in the query string. You can then write another PHP script to handle this URL, which can then retrieve the record in question using the supplied ID (`$_GET['id']`) and display a detail page or something.

You may want to look into PHP web frameworks, since doing all of this yourself can be tedious, error prone and vulnerable to attacks. Good frameworks have protection against things like SQL injection, XSRF etc, and abstract away most of the DB interaction.